# A kind of two numberings of pages

Tags: titles, page-numbering

Let's say I have the following .tex file :

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{amsart}
\begin{document}
\title{The title}
\author{The author}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % to keep track of subsubsections
\setcounter{section}{-1} % to number sections starting from 0
\newpage
\section{Introduction} % the 0 section

Blah blah

\section{First section} % the second section

Blah blah 2

\end{document}
```

The page numbering start from the page title with arabic numbers, and I would rather like it this way : no numbering up the the first page of the first section (the 0 section), then at this page starts (from 1) a roman numbering which ends at the last page of this 0 section, and after, and until the end, an arabic numeration (starting from 1 at the first page of the second section).

Comment: `\texttt{}` with a non text does not make sense.

Comment: Which as nothing to do with my question, but I will remove it anyway, to avoid digressions.

Comment: Could you requirement be simplified: No page numbers before the start of section 0. From first page of section 0, start with page number i (roman) until the end of the document? Or do you want to restart from i (roman) with every new section?

Comment: @Werner, I understood that the OP wants to change from roman to arabic at the last page of section 0.

Comment: @Werner Sigur perfectly understood. Roman up to the (an included) last page of section 0 and then (until the end) arabic. As I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combinations of `\pagenumbering{<style>} \setcounter{page}{1}` to adjust the setting of the page number (and reset it to 1 with every new style):

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}% No page numbering

\title{The title}
\author{The author}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{roman}% roman page numbering
\section{Introduction} % the 0 section

\lipsum[1-50]

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}% Arabic page numbering
\section{First section} % the second section

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

Note that this might cause problems if you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), as you may have duplicate destinations with regards to the title and ToC pages. To keep `hyperref` happy, you could use the following setup:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{amsart}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx,etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{-1}
\title{The title}
\author{The author}
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\ps@firstpage\ps@empty
\maketitle

\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\thepage}{}{}{}% Remove \thepage from \@evenhead
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{\thepage}{}{}{}% Remove \thepage from \@oddhead
\pagestyle{headings}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\endgroup

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Introduction} % the 0 section

\lipsum[1-50]

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{First section} % the second section

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

While `\pagenumbering{gobble}` will gobble `\thepage` from the visible page numbering, `hyperref` still uses `\thepage` for referencing purposes. So, we start the page numbering at a number that will naturally increase to `i` (roman) at the start of the first section; that is, `-1` in this case, and just remove `\thepage` from the header.

Comment: Thx a lot ! But... (as there's always a but) I'm using hyperref... How would you tweak your code to take a proper use of it into account then ?

Comment: Thx again ! Works perfectly.

Comment: @RobertGreen: I'm fixing something with this solution, but will update as soon as possible (and the references to this question).

Comment: Ok, perfect, thx. (Prefered to separate this initial question into itself "edited", and the new one you saw.)

Comment: Doesn't `\pagenumbering` always reset the `page`-counter to 1?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Correct... updated.