# Titlepage in amsart : how to include a picture in the title page?

Tags: graphics, titles

Let's say I have the following .tex file (coming from an answer to my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229749/a-kind-of-two-numberings-of-pages/229753#229753)) :

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}% No page numbering

\title{The title}
\author{The author}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{roman}% roman page numbering
\section{Introduction} % the 0 section

\lipsum[1-50]

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}% Arabic page numbering
\section{First section} % the second section

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

I would like to, with the smaller possible modifications, include a picture in the title page, and some text. I would like it to look like this one (with all dued respect to copyrights *etc*) :

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to put your image? and where the text?

Comment: I added an example in the edit to my question

Comment: Related: [How to customize my titlepage?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the `titlepage` option but the `titlepage` environment and insert whatever you want inside it.

An example

```
\documentclass[]{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}% No page numbering

\begin{titlepage}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\vspace*{1cm}

\title{The title}
\author{The author}
\maketitle
\vspace*{1cm}

Some text
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{roman}% roman page numbering
\setcounter{page}{1}% Reset page number
\section{Introduction} % the 0 section

\lipsum[1-50]

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}% Arabic page numbering
\setcounter{page}{1}% Reset page number
\section{First section} % the second section

\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @RobertGreen You're welcome.